# Fractional Integration by substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

[image]

The first part obviously indicates to simplify the question down to make it easier to look at

Thus by using (x-1) as a factor of x^3 -1 I arrive as formula
(2x+1)/(x^2 +1)

To integrate that you separate it out to two fractions and easily integrate each term to arrive at

$$2ln|x^2+1| + arctan(x) + c$$
but the book says the answer is $$ln|x^2+x+1| + c$$
Which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake was you forgot the $x$ term in $x^2+x+1$ when you factored $x^3-1$.

We have this:

$$\int\frac{2x^2-x-1}{x^3-1}dx$$

Factoring out $x-1$:

$$=\int\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}dx$$

Letting $u=x^2+x+1$ and $du=2x+1\;dx$:

$$=\int\frac{1}{u}du$$

Integrating and plugging $u$ back in:

$$=\ln|x^2+x+1|+C$$

Comment: The  absolute value is quite unnecessary.

Comment: I included it because his book did as well

Comment: I'd say that what goes with saying goes as well without :o)

Comment: Considering I'm too lazy to test if the expression is strictly nonnegative, I put them there to save me some needless work ;)

Comment: LoL.  But what if the upper and lower bounds of the integral are complex!!!  I don't feel the absolute values very much.

Comment: I'll let you know once I've taken complex analysis.

Comment: You don't have to test: it's well known its roots are the two complex cubic roots of $1$, hence it necessarily has a constant sign, and for $x=0$, it's positive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$x^3 - 1  = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Note:

$$2x^2 -x-1 = (x-1)(2x+1)$$

So your integrand becomes:

$$ \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}$$

Integrating the above is straight forward:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(x^2+x+1) = 2x + 1$$